# panda styling : export number-format to excel

Tags: python, pandas

the current Pandas styling [help page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel) mentions that

> The following pseudo CSS properties are also available to set excel specific style properties:

- `number-format`
  is supported for exporting to excel

However, there is no working example given and trying to adapt the provided functions, did not get me anywhere per below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def format2zero(val):
    frmat  = '{0:,.0f}'
    return 'number-format: %s' % frmat


np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

df.style.\
    apply(format2zero).\
    to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

I understand it's relatively new and wonderign if anyone get it working?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @jeschwar  a table in excel with zero decimal formatted values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have you use Excel terminology for `number-format` instead of python terminology.  In Excel when you right-click on a cell and select `Format cells/Custom` you will get some options and you can define your own.  I think `#,##0` is what you want to get zero decimal places:

```
def format2zero(val):
    return 'number-format: #,##0'
```

IIUC you should be using `df.style.applymap` instead of `df.style.apply` because you want `format2zero` applied to each *cell* instead of each row or column.

Making these two changes in your code gives me the following output when viewed in Excel:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   1       0  -1
1   2  -1  -1   1   0
2   3  -2   0   1   2
3   4   1   0   0   1
4   5   1   1   0   1
5   6  -1   1   1   0
6   7   0   1   0   2
7   8   0   1   0   1
8   9   2  -1   1  -2
9   10  0   1  -1   0
```