# how do you force write pandas styles to excel file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a data frame like this:

df

```
Server   CPU_Usage Memory Usage
Prod1    80        30
Prod2    70        10
Prod3    20        12
```

I need to apply Pandas Style to show % sign next to the numbers like below:

```
Server   CPU_Usage Memory_Usage
Prod1    80%        30%
Prod2    70%        10%
Prod3    20%        12%
```

I tried this:

```
df_style=df.style.format({'CPU_Usage':'{:}%', {'Memory_Usage':'{:}%')
```

When do df_style, it shows up on Jupyter notebook. But when I write this to excel as below:

```
df_style.to_excel(r'report.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Percent sign (%) disappear from the excel file. Any ideas to force writing % next to the CPU_Usage and Memory_Usage in excel file?

Comment: Your line `df_style=df.style.format({'CPU_Usage':'{:}%', {'Memory_Usage':'{:}%')` gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is adapting on [taller_ExcelHome's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085852/8508004) in conjunction with OP's use of `df_style=df.style.format()` to incorporate using the methods `df.style` methods to apply functions along with the `.to_excel()` method, and combining that with using Excel terminology for `number-format` that is able to be exported to Excel, as listed in [the documentation under 'Export to Excel'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel):

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Server': ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3'],
        'CPU_Usage': [80, 70, 20],
        'Memory_Usage': [30, 10, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def format2percent(val):
    return 'number-format: #\%' # add percent symbol in Excel terminology based https://stackoverflow.com/a/16807093/8508004 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56779532/8508004

df_style=df.style.format({'CPU_Usage':'{:}%', 'Memory_Usage':'{:}%'})

df_style.\
    map(format2percent).\
    to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
df_style
```

[image]

And how 'styled.xlsx' looks:

[image]

(If you are using a version of Pandas before 2.10, such as 1.5.1, use `applymap(format2percent).\` instead of `map(format2percent).\`. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap) about how "since version 2.1.0: Styler.applymap has been deprecated. Use Styler.map instead.")

Related to this question there is:

- ['panda styling : export number-format to excel'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56779532/8508004) did something similar with a different number formatting.
- ['Setting default number format when writing to Excel from Pandas'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51072652/8508004), might also guide you.

The Excel terminology for the formatting came from [this StackOverflow answer to 'Number format in excel: Showing % value without multiplying with 100'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16807093/8508004).

Note, you can test the 'number-format' syntax codes in the home ribbon in Excel if you add some numbers and then go to format number. Ultimately select 'custom codes' in there. It took some stumbling around in Microsoft's Help to even find how to activate it. [This guide](https://exceljet.net/articles/custom-number-formats) seem outdated but will give you an idea of what you are looking for in the Excel interface on the Home ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Server': ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3'],
        'CPU_Usage': [80, 70, 20],
        'Memory_Usage': [30, 10, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Format columns as percentages with a percent sign
df[['CPU_Usage', 'Memory_Usage']] = df[['CPU_Usage', 'Memory_Usage']].applymap(lambda x: f'{x}%')
excelFile = r"d:/temp/report.xlsx"
df.to_excel(excelFile, engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I need to do this in pandas style. The object needs to be pandas style object before writing to the excel file.

Comment: taller_ExcellHome, technically the 'number-format' is one of the available exporting styled DataFrames to Excel. It is listed in [the documentation under 'Export to Excel'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel). I added some SO posts in the comments below the OP that reference using it and then adapted your answer to illustrate how to piece it all together.

Comment: @Wayne You're right, your comment and post more directly answered the OP's question. But `applymap()` is eventually used to transform the column.

Comment: But not in the dataframe. I think since `Styler.applymap()` for styler is deprecated (see [here right now](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap)), I probably should add a note to use `Styler.map()` if you are using more current Pandas. I was using version 1.5.1. While yours is great the OP asked about using the styler.object in the comment below yours. I suspect OP wants to keep the data intact (raw) without making more deep copies around yet control display in Jupyter and Excel.