# From Html to Word document

Tags: python, html, css, html-table

I am generally trying to copy paste output of Jupyter notebooks cells to Word, notably stylized table (DataFrame displays).

For exemple I have:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['a','b','c']}).style.background_gradient('Blues')
```

Ref:

[image]

which I cannot directly copy-paste to word. I have tried other approaches (pandas `to_clipboard`, `pyperclip`...) but it will copy paste HTML code to Word.

So I was wondering how to easily change the HTML to Word table.

Typically:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['a','b','c']}).style.background_gradient('Blues').to_html()
```

Output a string:

> \n#T_74fd5_row0_col0 {\n  background-color:
> #f7fbff;\n  color: #000000;\n}\n#T_74fd5_row1_col0 {\n  background-color: #6aaed6;\n  color: #f1f1f1;\n}\n#T_74fd5_row2_col0
> {\n  background-color: #08306b;\n  color:
> #f1f1f1;\n}\n\n\n  \n    \n       \n      id="T_74fd5_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >a\n
> b\n
> \n  \n  \n    \n      0\n    
> 1\n      a\n    \n   
> \n      1\n      2\n      b\n    \n    \n      2\n      3\n      c\n    \n 
> \n\n

Any way to copy-paste this to word so it gives the good format ?

Comment: You might want to reconsider how you are approaching this. Pandas has a way to go to Microsoft with several of the stylings. Which styles are compatible are highlighted in the documentation, see the section 'Pandas to Excel' [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel). Then once you are in the Microsoft ecosystem you'll have an easier time to bring it from Excel to Word as you want.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091139/8508004) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091139/8508004).

Comment: yes yes I know, but can't justify using jupyter instead of Excel if I have to go back trough Excel to go to Words.

Comment: I don't dismiss them; I am actually looking to improve them (with a PR and my question here). I don't see anything bad saying something can be improved. Ultimately having a way to go directly from jupyter to word will increase jupyter usage.

Answer (score 0):

install python-docx

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

background_colors = [
    [RGBColor(247, 251, 255), RGBColor(106, 174, 214)],  # 1 column
    [RGBColor(8, 48, 107), RGBColor(247, 251, 255)]  # 2 column
]

# word document
doc = Document()

table = doc.add_table(rows=df.shape[0]+1, cols=df.shape[1])

# headers
for i, column_name in enumerate(df.columns):
    cell = table.cell(0, i)
    cell.text = str(column_name)
    cell.fill.solid()
    cell.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(220, 220, 220)

# data
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for col in range(df.shape[1]):
        cell = table.cell(row + 1, col)
        cell.text = str(df.iloc[row, col])

# save
doc.save('styled_table.docx')
```

Comment: How does it work with style ? (color, format ... etc.)